# Как выровнять по-центру внутри блока иконку и надпись?

Tags: css3, html5

Иконка и текст внутри каждого блока должны быть по-центру, но они не становятся

```css
.icons {
    font-family: RobotoRegular;
    font-size: 0.8vw;
    margin-top: 4%;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;   
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    text-align: center;
}
.icons div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.icons div div {
    display: block;
    flex: 1 0 0px;
}
.icons img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
  <div>
    <div class="icon1">
      <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon1.png">
      <p>Более 5 лет на рынке</p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon2">
      <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon2.png">
      <p>Сертификат ISO</p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon3">
      <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon3.png">
      <p>Член международной ассоциации GALA</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="icon4">
      <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon4.png">
      <p>Более 500 постоянных клиентов</p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon5">
      <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon5.png">
      <p>Более 12 000 часов устного перевода в год</p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon6">
      <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon6.png">
      <p>Более 120 000 переведенных страниц в год</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: обрати внимание на вот этот блок `.icons div div {
  display: block;
  flex: 1 0 0px;
  justify-content: center;
}` Тебя ничего не смущает?

Comment: не знаю, вроде норм, поставить flex: 1 0 0px; мне посоветовали в другом вопросе

Comment: Чтобы сработал `justify-content: center;`  `display:` должен быть `flex`

Comment: буду знать, но я его оттуда уже убрала, щас поменяю вопрос,они по-центру встали но теперь не ровно

Answer (score 0):

Изменения в данном блоке

```
.icons div div {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 0px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```css
.icons {
  font-family: RobotoRegular;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  margin-top: 4%;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.icons * {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
}

.icons div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.icons div div {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 0px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.icons img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.icons p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
  <div>
    <div class="icon1">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=Foto">
      <p>Более 5 лет на рынке</p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon2">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=Foto">
      <p>Сертификат ISO</p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon3">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/33ff99/555555?text=Foto">
      <p>Член международной ассоциации GALA</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="icon4">
      <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon4.png">
      <p>Более 500 постоянных клиентов</p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon5">
      <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon5.png">
      <p>Более 12 000 часов устного перевода в год</p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon6">
      <img src="../Eclipse/image/icon6.png">
      <p>Более 120 000 переведенных страниц в год</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```